# $X_n\rightarrow X$ in distribution then for $f\in C$, $f(X_n)\rightarrow f(X)$ in distribution?

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence

$X_n\rightarrow X$ in distribution then for $f\in C$ ,$f(X_n)\rightarrow f(X)$ in distribution?

Here is my attempt:

Consider $P(f(X_n)\leq x)=P(X_n^{-1}(f^{-1}(-\infty,x]))=P(X_n\in f^{-1}(-\infty,x]).$ By taking the limit, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}P(X_n\in f^{-1}(-\infty,x])=P(X \in f^{-1}(-\infty,x])=P(f(X)\leq x)$. One can conclude $f(X_n)\rightarrow f(X)$ in distribution. Is my logic correct, with the limit step following because convergence in distribution implies convergence in probability.

Comment: What is $C$ here? The space of continuous real-valued functions?

Comment: https://eventuallyalmosteverywhere.wordpress.com/2013/01/10/weak-convergence-and-the-portmanteau-lemma/

Comment: Yes C is the space of continous functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your argument is not correct. Convergence of $X_n$ in distribution to $X$ does not imply that $P(X_n \in A) \to P(X\in A)$ .

There is a therem which says that $X_n\to X$  in distribution iff $Eg(X_n) \to Eg(X)$ for every bounded continuous function $g$. Now this condition implies that $Eg(f((X_n)) \to Egf((X))$ because $g \circ f$ is a bounded continuous function. Hence $f(X_n) \to f(X)$ in distribution.

Comment: Can you offer any advice to someone who is trying to get better at proving things in probability theory. I seem to be able to follow most proofs but have trouble coming up with them on my own. Any advice would be appreciated.